# Accessing data array from plain javascript into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got some javascript code and I believe I've declared a global variable at the top. But then perhaps because I'm mixing jquery as well - is it that plain javascript becomes inaccessible halfway through the code?

My code is below:

```
var myArr = [];
myArr = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5
];

$(function() {
    $('.myclass').draggable({});
});

function accessMyArr(event) {
    alert("hello");
    alert(myArr);
}
```

I get the alert saying "hello", but after that the next alert is blank.
Why isn't javascript recognizing `myArr`? Is it not in the scope because of a jquery call or something?

Comment: sorry that was a typo - I've fixed it. It's a regular array

Comment: when do you call `accessMyArr()` ?

Comment: the big question is Alex's question. also, not sure what kind of event you are expecting on that function. Anyway, it works if you explicity call it: http://jsfiddle.net/ysah3f1v/

Answer (score -1):

You can declare and populate your array at the same time. Put what you want to be executed in your function and then afterwards call the function.

```
var myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function accessMyArr() {
    alert("hello");
    alert(myArr);
}

accessMyArr();
```